# How to make Eclipse ignore some files during lookup?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, there is the option to lookup a specific file by going to Navigate > Open Resource. Once the popup open, you can type to search for a file in the project. Is there any way to make this lookup ignore some files and not show them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible to do by "inclusion" (that is, telling Eclipse which files to include during the search), not by "exclusion" (telling Eclipse which files to exclude).

In the "Open Resource" dialog, notice that there's a small down-pointing arrow at the top right. From there, you can select the Working Set which will be considered during the search. You can define the working set as the collection of resources to consider during search; only resources that are contained within the working set will be shown.

Comment: Just remember that this setting stays for subsequent lookups. Otherwise you'll be frustrated, wondering why you can no longer find resources.